# is there an efficient way to propogate c# class deltas from a web api 2.2 app to a tester app?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

Is there an efficient way to propogate c# classes from a web api 2.2 app to a tester app? I have a Web API 2.2 app and I need to consume this service from a C# console tester app. So let's say that the Web API 2.2 app has models, request objects, etc. Whenever I cut a new version of the API I'm manually comparing all of the models, request objects, etc, b/t the API and the tester console app and then updating these classes in the tester app with any deltas.  These classes exist in my tester app, each with a namespace reflecting its existence in the tester app. So are there any processes or tools which would simplify the process of keeping these models and request classes in sync between these 2 apps?

Comment: You are asking about *schema* for REST APIs. Web API is used to create REST APIs. The de-facto standard is Swagger, now called OpenAPI. The most common way to do that is to add and configure the [Swashbuckle](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle) packages

Comment: Once you expose your schema through Swagger there are a *lot* of tools that can easily generate test proxies from it.

Comment: Of course, a quick&dirty solution form .NET projects *only* would be to put the DTOs into a separate class library project and use it in your console app. That *wouldn't* describe the controllers and actions though, just the DTOs

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you create your model in API project and have a duplicate of those classes in a test project and other projects and when you change a class in API you have to change same classes in other projects ...

you can separate your model classes in other project and then add reference model project, to API and test and all projects that you need so when you change a model its syncs in all projects

Answer (score 0):

Make a new Class Library project, put your models in there, then have both the app and webapi refer to the classes in that library. Then you can push that dll to both when it changes.